# How does this ruby snippet work?

Tags: ruby, hash

Conundrum:

```
something = {}
another = something
('a'...'f').each do |x|
  puts "another = #{another} and x= #{x} and something = #{something}"
  another = (another[x] ||= {})
end
puts something
```

Output:

```
=>another = {} and x= a and something = {}
=>another = {} and x= b and something = {"a"=>{}}
=>another = {} and x= c and something = {"a"=>{"b"=>{}}}
=>another = {} and x= d and something = {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{}}}}
=>another = {} and x= e and something = {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>{}}}}}
```

Now at first glance it would seem like 'another' and 'something' are both pointing to the same hash object, but if that were case then in the output 'another' would match 'something'. So then how is the variable 'something' not an empty hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, everything is an object and all objects are passed around using pointers (there are exceptions, but they don't apply here). When you do

```
something = {}
another = something
```

a single Hash object is created and both variables point to that same object. When you do

```
another[x] ||= {}
```

a single Hash object is created and *a pointer to that object* is added to *the Hash pointed to by* `another`. Another way to write that would be

```
old_hash = another
new_hash = {}
old_hash[x] = new_hash
another = new_hash
```

Remember: all of those assignments are just moving around pointers to objects. It should now be clear that `another` is pointing to the new (empty) hash. However, since `old_hash` *also contains a pointer* to the new hash, any futures changes to the new hash (i.e. `another`) will be seen by `old_hash`. That is why `something` grows with each iteration.

Your example is really no different from this simple situation:

```
x = {}
y = {}
z = {}
x["a"] = y
y["b"] = z
z["c"] = {}
puts x
# {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{}}}}
```

Your example just reverses the last three assignments - which makes no difference to the result.

Comment: I understand how that particular part works, what I don't understand is in every iteration of loop `something` grows while `another` stays empty. I would expect `another` to have a size of one and `something` to stay empty. Thank you for your response but I'm still unsure of the 'vodo' that is happening here. Maybe its just one of those things that  I should just leave at 'it works, thats why.'

Comment: There is no voodoo here. This behavior is a straightforward result of how Ruby handles assignment. I shall try to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> *Now at first glance it would seem like 'another' and 'something' are both pointing to the same hash object, but if that were case then in
>   the output 'another' would match 'something'.*

Because `something` and `another` are not pointing to the same objects anymore. You reassigned `another` with `another = (another[x] ||= {})`. You can verify it by calling `something.object_id` and `another.object_id`.

> *Why `another` is always `{}`*

Because when you do

`another = (another[x] ||= {})`

`another` is assigned value returned by evaluation of expression `(another[x] ||= {})` which is `{}` and that's why `another` becomes `{}`

And, for your code to work i.e., the way you expected just remove the reassignment of `another` so `another` and `something` point to the same object.

```
something = {}
another = something
('a'...'f').each do |x|
  puts "another = #{another} and x= #{x} and something = #{something}"
  another[x] ||= {}  ## Change to this
end
puts something
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
another = {} and x= a and something = {}
another = {"a"=>{}} and x= b and something = {"a"=>{}}
another = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}} and x= c and something = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}}
another = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}, "c"=>{}} and x= d and something = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}, "c"=>{}}
another = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}, "c"=>{}, "d"=>{}} and x= e and something = {"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}, "c"=>{}, "d"=>{}}
 => "a"..."f" 
2.1.0 :265 >     puts something
{"a"=>{}, "b"=>{}, "c"=>{}, "d"=>{}, "e"=>{}}
```